# Reuse same product image for multiple products

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

I use for some products the same 'product-image'.

> How do i reuse the same image for multiple products?

Comment: If u still not found your solution, you can try this link:  http://www.pixelpaul.net/magento-share-images-on-more-products/